# Как сделать csv таблицу с данными из списков

Tags: python, csv

У меня есть два списка names и links.
Как создать csv таблицу с данными из этих списков.

Answer (score 0):

Список в csv файл записывается с помощью

```
myFile = open('file.csv', 'w')
with myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    writer.writerows(names)
    writer.writerows(links)
```

Естественно, если вы захотите писать список не один за другим, а как-то по-другому, то придется соответствующую схему-структуру формировать.

Например, построчная запись в файл может быть выполнена методом writer.writerow

Comment: нужно что бы было типо колонка Names и под ней элементы списка names,затем колонка Links и под ней элементы links.

Comment: Ну, так в чем вопрос? Соединяете свои списки так, что-бы получился список списков, состоящих из двух элементов - один из Names, другой из Links. Но про это в вашем вопросе не было. А вот полученный таким образом список списков пишете в файл о чем вы и спросили. Одним из двух способов, которые я вам показал.  Но вообще-то структуры типа таблиц в Python гораздо разумнее обрабатывать -  и соответственно читать-писать в csv файл в виде DataFrame.